# My template.php stopped working

Tags: 7, theming

I have started building a new theme for my site. I use Foundation as the base theme and have followed the instructions in themes/zurb_foundation/STARTER/README.txt. I started off this work in a new GIT branch and everything seemed to work as expected, including functions in the template.php file. I then decided to merge this foundation branch to my master branch.

After activating the Foundation base theme and making my new sub theme the default theme in my master branch, everything works except for template.php which is now totally ignored. I have cleared all caches, I have run cron, I have double-checked the naming of the info file and all the functions in template.php... but I cannot get template.php to work.

Anyone? Maybe I should mention that compiling the custom.css file also still works.

Comment: do all the template functions in your template.php have your actual theme name?

Comment: No Sssweat: Yes, except for the ones that are locally called as sub functions within the file. And this exact same file worked in my separate  branch for this theme,

Comment: This is odd, maybe make a php error on one of the template.php lines and see if Drupal picks it up.

Comment: Good idea! I added some random characters in a function and immediately got a php error message... But I still don't get it. None of the functions actually works, I keep looking. And I wonder why I deserved a downvote on this question btw.

Comment: In which directory did you place template.php?

Comment: It's in the correct folder (theme root folder) and after re-doing all the steps of creating a new sub theme the template.php file now works except for two hook functions in relation to the foundation base theme (theme__system_main_menu and theme_links__topbar_main_menu). But that is not what I asked here, so I should probably post another question about that. Thanks anyway.